# Linq query with subquery

Tags: c#, linq

I have entity called UserPaymentHistory with Id, UserId, Price, PaymentDate.
I need to get that row which will have a User with last PaymentDate.

I can do query like this:

```
var lastPaymentDate =
    db.Repository<UserPayment>()
            .Where(u => u.UserId == 1)
            .Select(x => x.PaymentDate)
            .Max();
```

And then:

```
var userPayment = db.Repository<UserPayment>()
                      .Where(u => u.UserId == request.UserId 
                      && u.PaymentDate == lastPaymentDate).Single();
```

Is any way that I could get that record in one query ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order payments by PaymentDate in descending order and select first one:

```
var userPayment = db.Repository<UserPayment>()
                      .Where(u => u.UserId == request.UserId)
                      .OrderByDescending(u => u.PaymentDate)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```